# Change of syntax

Tags: arrays, json, vapor

I used to return my array of 'MapPoints' (from the db) using the following

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == MapPoints {
    func makeJSON() -> JSON {
        return .array(self.map { $0.makeJSON() })
    }

    func makeResponse(request: Request) throws -> Response {
        return try makeJSON().makeResponse()
    }
}
```

This now gives an error "Instance member 'array' cannot be used on type 'JSON'"

Can anyone tell me how this should be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Through an initialiser `JSON(array: [T])`.

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Post {
  func makeJSON() throws -> JSON {
    return try JSON(map { try $0.makeJSON() })
  }

  func makeResponse(request: Request) throws -> Response {
    return try makeJSON().makeResponse()
  }
}
```